# Get all queries from Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, tableau-api

I have connected Tableau to my Access database but I can't see all queries I made. For example some queries with calculated field or "IFs" don't show up on Tableau. I would like to access data directly by Tableau without each time exporting it to Excel.

Comment: Try creating temp tables from those queries with make-table queries: `SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM originalTable`. Possibly the ODBC connection or whatever API connects the two does not allow those special features.

Comment: Temp tables seems like reasonable approach. However, I would make the tables permanent and then delete/write records as needed. Creating and deleting tables is design change and frequent design changes can cause db bloat, necessitating Compact and Repair to free file capacity. I don't think an established db should require frequent C&R. If the db is split design with multiple users, the temp tables must reside in front end and each user runs their own copy (which they should already be doing).